# Wordpress Blog - How to hide Meta Widget to guest users

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my web site the blog section created in word press, I want to hide the META widget to guest users, but it should be displayed in admin . I found the code in sidebar.php( wp-content/themes/sidebar.php) page, but i don't know how to display this widget only for admin?

Please any one help me!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can determine if the current user is an administrator by checking if they have access to one of the admin-only privileges:

```
if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
    //code to display your widget
}
```